# PHP script installation progress steps?

Tags: php, forms, installation, push

Some scripts don't have javascript to refresh the page itself but when they are performing step by step installation, they can auto push new texts / steps / instructions to the web page.

How do they do this?

Comment: Please modify your question, clearify it and add some sample code if necessary. This question does not make sense.

Comment: I think with "refreshing" you mean postback - you press next and server responds you with a new page. The webserver can respond to you with whatever you like depending on the data the user has inputted. Because when you press "next" the webserver receives that data (a request has been made) and then responds with a new page (response has been made)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear  to me from your question what you mean (or pretty broad), this depends on how this was done, so a concrete example would be useful.

Anyway, normally this is done by creating an installer session and then submitting forms to a controller which will handle the input and decide upon the input and the current session's state what to display next.